# AutoMapper with complex types

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, automapper

I'm having a problem trying to use complex types with [AutoMapper](http://automapper.codeplex.com).

I have two objects, a domain and a ViewModel that utlize in my View;

**ViewModel**

```
public class RegisterCoupleModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "campo obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "Primeiro nome", Order = 0, GroupName = "Noivo")]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string FistNameGroom
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "campo obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "Último nome", Order = 1, GroupName = "Noivo")]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string LastNameGroom
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "campo obrigatório")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$", ErrorMessage = "Formato de email inválido.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Remote("IsEmailAvailable", "Validation", "", ErrorMessage = "este email já está sendo usado por outro usuário.")]
    [Display(Name = "Email", Order = 2, GroupName = "Noivo")]
    [StringLength(180)]
    public string EmailGroom
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "campo obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "Primeiro nome", Order = 0, GroupName = "Noiva")]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string FistNameBride
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "campo obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "Último nome", Order = 1, GroupName = "Noiva")]
    [StringLength(60)]
    public string LastNameBride
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "campo obrigatório")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$", ErrorMessage = "Formato de email inválido.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Remote("IsEmailAvailable", "Validation", "", ErrorMessage = "este email já está sendo usado por outro usuário.")]
    [Display(Name = "Email", Order = 2, GroupName = "Noiva")]
    [StringLength(180)]
    public string EmailBride
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "campo obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name = "Url")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\+]{5,22}$", ErrorMessage = "Chave inválida")]
    [StringLength(22, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = "A chave deve ter entre {0} e {1} caracteres.")]
    [Remote("IsKeywordAvaliable", "Validation")]
    public string UrlKeyword
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    [Display(Name = "Voce é humano?")]
    [UIHint("ReCaptcha")]
    public string ReCaptcha
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

**Domain Object**

```
public class Couple
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string UrlKeyword { get; set; }
    public virtual Partner Groom { get; set; }
    public virtual Partner Bride { get; set; }
    public DateTime Marriage { get; set; }
    public DateTime Dating { get; set; }
    public DateTime Engagement { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

If you look you will see that my object `Couple` domain has the properties has `Bride` and `Groom` which are actually the **same type**.

How can I map my domain object `Couple` with the `RegisterCoupleModel`?

**Here I made it as far as:**

In settings automapper tried to do something like:

```
CreateMap<RegisterCoupleModel, Couple>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Bride.User.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.FistNameBride))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Bride.User.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.LastNameBride))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Bride.User.Email, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.EmailBride))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Groom.User.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.FistNameGroom))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Groom.User.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.LastNameGroom))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Groom.User.Email, opt => opt.MapFrom(source => source.EmailGroom));
```

But the error below is displayed:

> Expression 'dest => dest.Bride.User.FirstName' must resolve to
>   top-level member. Parameter name: lambdaExpression

**I know this takes the act of trying to use to map properties with nested types.**

But how can I map `RegisterCoupleModel` to `Couple` and the two properties `Bride` and `Groom` are the same type?

I found a [question here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4928487/how-to-automap-thismapping-sub-members) that looks like this, but it helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i would do is encapsulate the properties for **FirstNameBride**, **LastNameBride**, **EmailBride**, **FirstNameGroom**, **LastNameGroom**, **EmailGroom** into a nested viewmodel type, let's say `PersonDetails`:

```
public class PersonDetails
{
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And update your parent VM accordingly:

```
public class RegisterCoupleModel
{
   public PersonDetails GroomDetails { get; set; }
   public PersonDetails BrideDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can provide the mapping from `PersonDetails` to `User` (or whatever type Groom.User is):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<PersonDetails,User>();
```

Note how i've got so explict property mapping -> because the fields have the same name in the source and destination, so no explicit mapping is required. Always try and do this where possible. Less code -> better code.

Then in addition to the above mapping, simply do this:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<RegisterCoupleModel, Couple>();
```

And AutoMapper will see that `RegisterCoupleModel` has two `PersonDetails` objects, see it already has a mapping definition, then automatically use that.

That should work (i've done it before).

You shouldn't always use flat viewmodels, nest them where necessary (such as reusing fields).

Comment: But how would the attributes?

If encapsulate these fields, the settings of the attributes are the same for the bride and groom.

So for example I can not change the display text or GrupName for Display attribute.

Comment: @Riderman - use some OO tricks, for example make `PersonDetails` abstract, then create derived classes for `BrideDetails` and `GroomDetails`. Set the common attributes in the base, then override the different ones.

Comment: I use the helper: `@Html.EditorForModel()` to generate the form, but it does not generate nested types.
How can I encapsulate these three properties and make the helper continues to display them in the form?

Comment: @Riderman - create a custom editor template for `PersonDetails`